# cover schedulable batch class in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, schedulebatch, customlabel

//In this a custom label `SFA_AMERICAS_BATCH_JOB_FILTER`
how to cover in test class

```
global class SFA_ScheduleDailyAccountBatchForAmerica implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        String filterStr =LABEL.SFA_AMERICAS_BATCH_JOB_FILTER;
        SFA_UpdateAccountBatch b = new SFA_UpdateAccountBatch(filterStr,false,true);
        database.executebatch(b,10);

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_scheduling_2.htm

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or are you just hoping we'll do your work for you? Your questions will be much better received if you demonstrate that you have made an effort to solve them yourself. Also storing an entire `WHERE` clause in a `Custom Label` seems like a pretty bad idea. You should instead just store the value you want to filter against (e.g. `Region - America` instead of `Region__c = 'Region - America'`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a patttern that's worked for me. In your schedulable Class you want to add a conditional block that runs only during tests....

```
global class SFA_ScheduleDailyAccountBatchForAmerica implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        String filterStr =LABEL.SFA_AMERICAS_BATCH_JOB_FILTER;
        SFA_UpdateAccountBatch b = new SFA_UpdateAccountBatch(filterStr,false,true);
        database.executebatch(b,10);

        //Add this block for test support purposes...
        if(test.isRunningTest()){
            Account a = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name = 'testScheduledApexFromTestMethod'];
            a.name = 'testScheduledApexFromTestMethodUpdated';
            update a;
       }
       //End test support

    }
}
```

Here's the test Class.

```
@isTest
private class ScheduleDailyAccountBatchForAmerica_test {
    // CRON expression: midnight on March 15.
    // Because this is a test, job executes
    // immediately after Test.stopTest().
    public static String CRON_EXP = '0 0 0 15 3 ? 2022';

    static testmethod void test() {
        Test.startTest();

        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name = 'testScheduledApexFromTestMethod';
        insert a;

        // Schedule the test job
        String jobId = System.schedule('ScheduleApexClassTest', CRON_EXP, new SFA_ScheduleDailyAccountBatchForAmerica());

        // Get the information from the CronTrigger API object
        CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime FROM CronTrigger WHERE id = :jobId];

        // Verify the expressions are the same
        System.assertEquals(CRON_EXP, ct.CronExpression);

        // Verify the job has not run
        System.assertEquals(0, ct.TimesTriggered);

        // Verify the next time the job will run
        System.assertEquals('2022-03-15 00:00:00', String.valueOf(ct.NextFireTime));

        // Verify the scheduled job hasn't run yet.
        System.assertNotEquals('testScheduledApexFromTestMethodUpdated', [SELECT id, name FROM account WHERE id = :a.id].name);

        Test.stopTest();

        // Now that the scheduled job has executed after Test.stopTest(),
        System.assertEquals('testScheduledApexFromTestMethodUpdated', [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :a.Id].Name);
    }
}
```

So... test Class runs, creates one account, invokes scheduler, which enters the test.isRunningTest() block, and updates that Account. The Assertions before and after the test.stopTest() statement verify that the scheduler actually ran and updated that Account.name.

Comment: The batch will not execute.

Comment: The batch (should) have it's own test Class, this just tests the scheduler.

Comment: But your last assertion seems to assume you can assert on the behavior of the batch?

Comment: @AdrianLarson That's right... I edited my answer to include a pretty important detail! Thanks for helping me offer up a _complete_ answer!

Comment: I like a lot of the pieces of this answer, but I really can't up-vote any answer that contains a check on `Test.isRunningTest`. That function should basically never be used unless all alternatives have been exhausted imo. The right way to test the batch piece is to execute the batch itself. The schedule test should test the schedule unit of code, and the batch test should test the batch unit.

Comment: Thanks @John Thompson its working and cover test class 100%

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand you issue since custom labels can be accessed during test methods.

However, to cover all situations you could do something like this:

```
global class SFA_ScheduleDailyAccountBatchForAmerica implements Schedulable {

    @TestVisible private static string TESTFILTER;

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        String filterStr = TESTFILTER == null ? LABEL.SFA_AMERICAS_BATCH_JOB_FILTER : TESTFILTER;
        SFA_UpdateAccountBatch b = new SFA_UpdateAccountBatch(filterStr,false,true);
        database.executebatch(b,10);

    }
}
```

Then in your test:

```
SFA_ScheduleDailyAccountBatchForAmerica() sch = New SFA_ScheduleDailyAccountBatchForAmerica();
sch.TESTFILTER = 'Region__c = \'Region - America\'';

String jobId = System.schedule('ScheduleApexClassTest', CRON_EXP, sch);
//proper asserts and wrap in Test.starttest() as appropriate
```

OR for no value set

```
SFA_ScheduleDailyAccountBatchForAmerica() sch = New SFA_ScheduleDailyAccountBatchForAmerica();
sch.TESTFILTER = '';

String jobId = System.schedule('ScheduleApexClassTest', CRON_EXP, New SFA_ScheduleDailyAccountBatchForAmerica());
```

This will provide you with the most flexibility to test many cases and not relying on the actual current value of the label:

1. Label not set - Assert No Results modified
2. Label Set - Assert record updates as appropriate
3. Label Set Wrong (Set the TESTFILTER to a wrong value) - Assert errors caught and records are or are not modified per conditions.

Basically you are not limited to the Label in your tests and can create a testing suite that covers any possibility. Since the property is private and @TestVisible it can only be used during tests.